# Extracting Information from a Ruby String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a text file similar to this on a remote device:

```
 D0-23-DB-31-04-3E%20192.168.4.42%20dnat
 68-A8-6D-0C-38-B2%20192.168.4.40%20dnat
```

I created a small Ruby script to convert this to a string and post it to my Rails application:

```
 def chilli_list
  hash = File.open("/tmp/client_list", "rb").read
  return hash
 end
```

The output then looks like:

```
"D0-23-DB-31-04-3E%20192.168.4.42%20dnat\n68-A8-6D-0C-38-B2%20192.168.4.40%20dnat\n"
```

I need to extract the information bit by bit and display in a view. So far, I've not got far. I tried the following which is OK:

```
str = "D0-23-DB-31-04-3E%20192.168.4.42%20dnat\n68-A8-6D-0C-38-B2%20192.168.4.40%20dpass\n" 

str.each_line do |line|
  puts line.split(" ").first
  puts line.split(" ").second
end
```

Is that the best way to do it or is there a better way?

Finally and most importantly, I also need to perform a few calculations on the string. I can count the lines with `str.lines.count`, but what I need is a count of the lines where the third value `== nat` as in the example above.

How can I go about that?

Comment: "%20" is a URI escape or "percent escape". It is *not* a space character. It just represents the encoding of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here's how to convert from HTML encoding back into a normal string:

```
require 'uri'
URI.decode('D0-23-DB-31-04-3E%20192.168.4.42%20dnat') # => "D0-23-DB-31-04-3E 192.168.4.42 dnat"
```

Here's how to break the entire string into separate decode lines:

```
"D0-23-DB-31-04-3E%20192.168.4.42%20dnat\n68-A8-6D-0C-38-B2%20192.168.4.40%20dnat\n".split("\n")
  .map{ |l| URI.decode(l) }
```

which results in this array in IRB:

```
[
    [0] "D0-23-DB-31-04-3E 192.168.4.42 dnat",
    [1] "68-A8-6D-0C-38-B2 192.168.4.40 dnat"
]
```

Add on `.count{ |l| l[/ dnat$/] }` to the end of the previous command and you'll have your count:

```
"D0-23-DB-31-04-3E%20192.168.4.42%20dnat\n68-A8-6D-0C-38-B2%20192.168.4.40%20dnat\n".split("\n")
  .map{ |l| URI.decode(l) }
  .count{ |l| l[/ dnat$/] }
```

Which returns `2`.

You could also probably simplify the whole process by just directly counting the number of `'nat'` occurrences:

```
"D0-23-DB-31-04-3E%20192.168.4.42%20dnat\n68-A8-6D-0C-38-B2%20192.168.4.40%20dnat\n".scan('nat').count
```

Which also returns `2`.

Comment: coolio, I was miles off clearly! Very interesting, thanks. Was the way I approached getting the individual values out ok (split(' ').first or is there also a better way for that too?