# Collection of Strings to Form Single Array in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following on from a question I had last week about decoding a string, I'm trying to work out how I can decode the string and then join with a string from many other objects.

In the console, I had it working fine - I just cannot get it working in the browser..

My locations have many clients. Each client has a query_string which looks something like this:

```
 "00-24-D7-04-10-A8 192.168.4.132 pass 5035077a00000004 tbPUEVj 0/3600 29792537/0\nC8-60-00-16-63-67 192.168.4.129 dnat 503505fb00000009 - 0/0 0/0\n60-C5-47-96-31-FC 192.168.4.123 dnat 50350c3e00000001 tbgJ9aj 0/0 48020478/0\n"
```

I can decode this but I can't figure out how I can merge many of these.

In the console, I've tried this:

```
 l.nas.map { |f| f.query_string }.each do |t|
   puts t
 end
```

That gives me:

```
 8C-FA-BA-60-7D-95 192.168.6.161 pass 5034917000000001 xxx-1adae9 10/0 3408756/0
 28-37-37-21-4C-04 192.168.6.160 pass 50348a630000000b xxx-1adae9 1/0 30258694/0
 00-24-D7-04-10-A8 192.168.4.132 pass 5035077a00000004 tbPUEVj 0/3600 29792537/0
 C8-60-00-16-63-67 192.168.4.129 dnat 503505fb00000009 - 0/0 0/0
 60-C5-47-96-31-FC 192.168.4.123 dnat 50350c3e00000001 tbgJ9aj 0/0 48020478/0


 ["8C-FA-BA-60-7D-95 192.168.6.161 pass 5034917000000001 xxx-1adae9 10/0 3408756/0\n28-37-37-21-4C-04 192.168.6.160 pass 50348a630000000b xxx-1adae9 1/0 30258694/0\n", "00-24-D7-04-10-A8 192.168.4.132 pass 5035077a00000004 tbPUEVj 0/3600 29792537/0\nC8-60-00-16-63-67 192.168.4.129 dnat 503505fb00000009 - 0/0 0/0\n60-C5-47-96-31-FC 192.168.4.123 dnat 50350c3e00000001 tbgJ9aj 0/0 48020478/0\n"]
```

I've also tried:

```
 l.nas.map { |f| f.query_string.split('\n') }.each do |t|....
```

How can I join these strings together and then break them down properly. Or break them apart and join together?

My previous post: [Extracting Information from a Ruby String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959047/extracting-information-from-a-ruby-string)

Comment: "two hashes joined together" - that looks like two strings.

Comment: Exactly what output are you expecting?

Comment: @alfonso I need it broken down so I can loop through each and do a few calcs to each one. Basically line by line like the console output.